# Moment equilibrium equation of beam

Tags: beam

[image]

The above beam is loaded by a distributed load per unit length of the referential scale defined by
the vector field ***q* = *q(x)*** and a distributed moment load vector per unit length ***m* = *m(x)***. As a consequence of the external loads, the beam is deformed into the so-called current state where the external loads are balanced by an internal section force vector ***F* = *F(x)*** and an internal section moment vector ***M* = *M(x)***

The internal force ***F*** has normal component $N$ and shear components $Q_y$ and $Q_z$ and the internal moment has the respective components $M_x$, $M_y$, and $M_z$. The equations of equilibrium are as follows:

[image]

**What I don't understand is why is the cross product of the unit vector $i$ with $dF$ equal to zero? Thank you.**

[Source of the tutorial](http://homes.civil.aau.dk/jc/FemteSemester/Beams3D.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because unit vector $i$ is parallel to the $dF$.

In the diagram, they show $F$ in an angle, but it's not correct. In a beam bending stress and the resultant force are always axial, parallel with the centroid of the beam.

Comment: So both $dF$ and $F$ cancel right? So the equation is wrong?

Comment: What you said is not right. Because if that is the case, then i * F should also be equal to zero.

Comment: not necessarily. But the cross product of unit vector i is parallel to dF, both align with the x-axis. and we know the cross-product of parallel vectors is zero.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq, I never said F or dF is zero!  They are parallel to the x-axis so is the unit vector i, therefore their cross product is zero!

Comment: Thank you Kamran!

Comment: @user134613, thank you for seeing my point.

Comment: @kamran, i still think you are wrong. Because F and dF both must lie on the same axis, since dF means infinitesimal small change in F. So if the cross product of i and dF is zero if both are lying on the same axis, then cross product of i and F must also be zero because then F also lies on the same axis as i. I still don't think this answer what you have given is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they are assuming dF is extremely small, for a length change of dx, as compare to dM (which is relatively much larger than dF). So we can put dF to be equal to zero for simplifications.